# Scrapy Product datas in a json script / tags cannot be targeted

Tags: json, xpath, scrapy

I can parse the json datas in a script, but I am not able to target specific tags.

If it would be a "normal" script type like "application/ld+json", it would be pretty easy to collect what I need. But I cannot address the script name, cause there is no name 
So I used the XPATH selector to the script via dev tools.

So, I read the json datas in a Scrapy shell from a [product link](https://www.electronic4you.de/makita-dmp180z-akku-kompressor-189153.html)

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.electronic4you.de/makita-dmp180z-akku-kompressor-189153.html' ...
...
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="root-wrapper"]/div/script[5]/text()').get()
```

And I get all datas in the script, of course. The result shows us:

> ['new E4uTrack("view_item", {"currency":"EUR","value":"49","page_type":"product","title":"Makita DMP180Z Akku-Kompressor","items":[{"item_name":"Makita DMP180Z Akku-Kompressor","item_id":"189153","id":"189153","item_mpn":"DMP180Z","item_gtin":"0088381898263","item_brand":"MAKITA","google_business_vertical":"retail","price":"49","currency":"EUR","regular_price":109.9501,"screensize":"","vogels_fsf":false}]})']

Normally I would targeting a value - e.g. the value from "item_name" with:

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.electronic4you.de/makita-dmp180z-akku-kompressor-189153.html' ...
...
>>> script_tag = response.xpath('//*[@id="root-wrapper"]/div/script[5]/text()').get()
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(script_tag)["items"]["item_name"]
```

But......

The output shows us:

> File "",
> line 1
> json.loads(script_tag)["item_name"]
> IndentationError: unexpected indent

I have two questions.

Do I address the script correctly with the xpath selector? And how I can target from this script only tags I need?

Comment: Would you share the url or update with your full code? The error you have showed here is indentation error is not reproducible just correct the indentation.

Comment: Yes of course. The URL is https://www.electronic4you.de/makita-dmp180z-akku-kompressor-189153.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the ResultSet and pull the desired data

```
import scrapy
import json
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.electronic4you.de/makita-dmp180z-akku-kompressor-189153.html']

    def parse(self, response):

        script_tag =  response.xpath('(//*[@id="root-wrapper"]/div/script)[5]/text()').re_first(r'E4uTrack\("view_item",(.+?)\)$')
        json_data= json.loads(script_tag)

        for item in json_data["items"]:
            yield {
                'Name':item["item_name"]
                }
```

**Output:**

```
{'Name': 'Makita DMP180Z Akku-Kompressor'}
```

Comment: F-Hoque, Yes it works fine  I would never come to the idea to iterate over the xpath resultset ! Interesting. Just one thought more: You address the script via the xpath selector. But if the position of the script changes on another product page, for those cases using the regular expression from @gangabass (there is just a problem with invalid expression).

Comment: The following expression also works: `script_tag =  response.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"view_item")]/text()').re_first(r'E4uTrack\("view_item",(.+?)\)$')`

Comment: Hmm, I was playing around with it. So, I was near to the right expression, but I gave up on it. My expression was: json_raw = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "view_item")]/text()').re_first(r'E4uTrack\("view_item",(.+?)\)$') there is a space between text(), /text() and I used "//script"instead "//*"  I think I have to go diving into xpath cheatsets. Thank you, it's a useful help for me, F-Hoque  

Answer (score 2):

You need to use regular expression to clear XPath result:

```
json_raw = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "E4uTrack(\"view_item\"")]/text()').re_first(r'E4uTrack\("view_item",(.+?)\)$')
data = json.loads(json_raw)
```